# Set up serial on start up Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to set up so that I don't have to type in these two commands after boot up (PI as user):

1) sudo CHMOD 777 /dev/ttyAMA0

2) sudo stty -F /dev/ttyAMA0 cs8 9600 -brkint -imaxbel -opost -onlcr -isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echoctl -echoke noflsh -ixon -crtscts

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add it to the end of /etc/rc.local,

```
CHMOD 777 /dev/ttyAMA0 &
stty -F /dev/ttyAMA0 cs8 9600 -brkint -imaxbel -opost -onlcr -isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echoctl -echoke noflsh -ixon -crtscts &
```

Comment: Right now, I see:
    _IP=$(hostname -I) || true
    if ["$_IP"]; then
        printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
    fi
just add the code here?

Answer (score 1):

You can add your script executable command to the bottom of `.bashrc` that will run your script every time you log in.

If you are looking for a solution that works on bootup to the console, take a look at [this link](http://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2012/06/raspberry-pi-run-program-at-start-up.html).

If you want a script to run when you boot into the LXDE environment, you could take a look at [this Raspberry Pi forum post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=11256).

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/8735